# Take input from the user using java

Tags: java, input, console

I am creating a console using this method

```
MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("", null);
console.activate();
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
        .addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console });
MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(stream, true));
```

I tried the normal method I use for taking an input but it's not working
Here is the code I tried

[1] This prints 'Enter a string' but doesn't allow you to write in the console

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered string " + s);
```

[2] and this prints `null`

```
BufferedReader columnInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        System.in));
try {
    System.out.println(columnInput.readLine());
    // System.out.println("#read mflkerf: " );
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered string " + s);
```

does work. I'm guessing because you reassigned standard output stream using `System.setOut` you no longer see the output printed from `System.out.println`

Try creating a thread that prints your new console outputstream into a file or somewhere and you will see the output

Comment: I don't quite understand .. I used System.setOut in order to be able to use System.out.println .. System.out.println is working fine